# Asking for suggestions about square numbers

Tags: square-numbers

Please let me excuse first. It is embarrassing but I know nothing about math; but when I played with the square numbers with my calculator while slacking of my paper work yesterday (like, press 4 then √, then 9 and √, 16 and √; continuously until I got bored~ haha...), it happened to extend further.. (please see the photos)

Excuse me if it looks confusing and messy, I have no idea what I was writing, too

I just found it interesting and quite fun, and it made my brain fresh. I want to read about it but I do not know how to search for it, I do not know any key words or what is it about, because I threw math back to the teacher's face since I finished high school . Nearly 20 years ago...

I would like to ask what is this kind called, and can I have some links to tables like this to learn it more, please.

(Is this even math... I wonder...)

Thank you in advanced!

P.S. I cannot embed the photos yet, please follow the links.

[(Picture 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP4wx.jpg)
[(Picture 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VskmI.jpg)
[(Picture 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moJPe.jpg)
[(Picture 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc4ti.jpg)
[(Picture 5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/getNy.jpg)
[(Picture 6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q44e0.jpg)

Comment: A few things. Don't apologize about not knowing math, we all started from zero at some point. I like the kinds of ideas you are thinking about, but the pictures are a little hard to read (cute doodles, though). If you could typeset the ideas, that would be great.

Comment: Thank you very much Don. I will try to typeset them as well as I can (or write them in more organized way...) and once it is done, I will come back to explain it again!

P.S. The doodles are not mine xD they are printed on the notebook. They are Gudetama xDD

Comment: Don, I've posted them already. Could you please give them a look again, please?
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412849/continue-about-square-numbers

Comment: I'm sleepy. Tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't mean right after I said xD Thank you, Don.

Comment: You calculated so-called square-roots. The square root of a non-negative number $\ x\ $ is defined as the (unique) non-negative number $\ y\ $ which satisfies $\ y^2=x\ $ and the notation is $\ \sqrt{x}\ $. Is this what you are asking for ?

Comment: Nope, Peter, but thank you so much :D