# (Again) About square numbers

Tags: square-numbers

Here I am again, trying to organize my thought. Thank you Don for encouraging me yesterday. (From this thread [Asking for suggestions about square numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411923/asking-for-suggestions-about-square-numbers))

I'll try to explain as much as I can, but some parts I really don't know how to explain them...

---

When you look at the differences between each of the sq number, you find that the differences increase steadily with +2 to each. I call it layers until steady. (Just want some words to identify it).

[layers of ^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZInS.jpg)

We can see that numbers of layers agree with number of the ^
(I don't know what is the word for the ^....). See the ^3 layers

[layers of ^3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqp3Z.jpg)

Same goes with ^4 and ^5 and above

[layers of ^4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7rbt.jpg)

[layers of ^5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWpmk.jpg)

---

Now let's take a look at a concrete picture of 3^2 and 4^2

[3^2 and 4^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StjDr.jpg)

If we want to find their differences, we pull 1 from each ball from 4^2 (to make each ball has 3), we need to pull only 3 balls because we're making them 3^2; and we have one of the 4^2 ball left.

Thus, 4^2 - 3^2 = [3x3](3, which remain in each ball after we pulled 1 out) + 3(pulled from three of the 4^2 balls) + 4 (that ball left from 4^2)

See more picture, please.

[20^2 and 21^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlQem.jpg)

[22^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voC0Q.jpg)

[60^2 and 61^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE1tm.jpg)

I'll continue in here [(Continue) About square numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412849/continue-about-square-numbers) because I my reputation is not enough to post more than 8 links.

Comment: Oh... we can't add photos in comments T_T what should I do

Comment: If you could summarise your question in 1 sentence, what is it? (Also I haven't seen those circular and rectangular diagrams before)

Comment: Dear helpme, it's from this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411923/asking-for-suggestions-about-square-numbers (I should add this to my post).

that diagram is my version of it....

Comment: I think I have to use another thread to post the rest T_T only few photos left.

Comment: I am also not quite understanding what your final question is, but it appears at a glance that you are discovering some of the recursive nature of sequences of $n$'th powers and differences of consecutive $n$'th powers.  Much of this is already well understood and has been for millenia.  It can be proved formally with algebra and/or induction.  For instance, $(n+1)^2 = n^2+2n+1 = n^2 + n + (n+1)$.  This can of course continue, $(n+1)^2 = n^2+n+(n+1) = (n-1)^2 + (n-1)+n+n+(n+1)$ and so forth ad nauseum.  Similar identities exist for higher powers.

Comment: Dear JMoravitz, that's what I want to know... unfortunately, I don't think I understand the terms T_T. I have some more photos to post, do you think I can start a new threat to post the rest of them?

Comment: You can try using imgur album

Comment: Thank you I'll try that!

Comment: It doesn't work... It limits numbers of link I can add, including links pasted from my own upload...

Comment: Put your physical pieces of paper side by side and take a picture of multiple at once

Comment: Dear helpme, I just tried that with picture collage, but I have 8 more picture TwT If I snap them together to put every of them in 8 photos, it will be too small to read. I think I'll just use another thread T_T please excuse my inappropriate manner of using webboard.

Answer (score 1):

For any sequence $u_n$, define the *forward difference* $\Delta u_n:=u_{n+1}-u_n$, in analogy with the derivative $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ of a continuous function $f$. Your first finding is $\Delta n^2=2n+1$. We can iterate $\Delta$, e.g. $\Delta^2u_n:=\Delta(\Delta u_n)$ so $\Delta^2n^2=2$. The pattern you've found is $\Delta^kn^k=k!$ for any integer $k\ge0$ (in analogy with $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}x^k=k!$). To prove this, it suffices to note from the binomial theorem that $\Delta n^k$ is a degree-$(k-1)$ polynomial in $n$ with leading coefficient $k$.

Comment: Thank you J.G.... I'm so sorry I don't understand the signs (T_T; do you think I can have more simple version of them to read, please...?

Comment: @PacharapanK My first equation tells you what $\Delta$ means in this context. Each of your "layers" goes from a sequence, say $u_n$, to the corresponding $\Delta u_n$.

Comment: Does the  Δ have a name...? What do we call it?

Comment: @PacharapanK A [forward difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Forward,_backward,_and_central_differences), as I said. Well, it's a first forward difference; $\Delta^ku_n$ is a $k$th forward difference.

Comment: Thank you. And what is the  called, please?

Comment: @PacharapanK Oh, $u_n$ is just a common notation for the $n$th term in whatever sequence we're interested in. When I discussed your first example, I took $u_n$ to be $n^2$.

Comment: I've posted the rest,and if it's ok with you, could you please take a look and convert it to some specific terms for me again, so that I can search for them. Thank you very much!
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412849/continue-about-square-numbers